# Python Crawler and autoLogin

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-crawler

everyone. I am new to python. And I want to fetch the data from our school website. And before that, I want to do auto login. 
Here is our schools' website "http://ams.bhsfic.com". What's more, I tried to record the real URL for the login, and when I clicked on the real one, it signed "404".
And here is the code

```
import urllib
import urllib2
import cookielib
class Login:
    def __init__(self):
        self.loginUrl = 'http://ams.bhsfic.com/system/login/doLogin'
        self.cookies = cookielib.CookieJar()
        self.postdata = urllib.urlencode({
            'emall': '20160612',
            'userPwd': 'At121212'
        })
        self.opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(self.cookies))

    def getPage(self):
        request = urllib2.Request(
            url=self.loginUrl,
            data=self.postdata)

        result = self.opener.open(request)
        print result.read().decode('gbk')


login = Login()
login.getPage()
```

The bug:

```
Connected to pydev debugger (build 172.3544.46)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 1599, in <module>
    globals = debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None, is_module)
  File "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 1026, in run
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "/Users/mac/PycharmProjects/crawler/crawler", line 23, in <module>
    sdu.getPage()
  File "/Users/mac/PycharmProjects/crawler/crawler", line 18, in getPage
    result = self.opener.open(request)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 437, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 550, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 475, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 409, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 558, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You're getting a 404 error because the page `http://ams.bhsfic.com/system/login/doLogin` does not exist. 
Instead try "posting" to `http://ams.bhsfic.com/system/login`which does. 
Be aware that if your site has any CSRF token (or equivalent) you'll have to deal with them also.

Alternatively you can try using [Selenium](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) . It simulates real user interactions. So you can "select" username/password fields and "click" Login button.